# How to output selected elements of a dataset using awk

Tags: awk

I have a dataset of numbers arranged in rows and columns. The dataset has "NULL" values, which I want to get rid of. I have used awk to do this and my script is shown below. I don't get an error when I ran it, but there is no output either. I have to do Ctrl+d to abort the process. I can't think of an obvious reason why this won't work; what is wrong here?

```
{       for (i=1;i<=NF;i+1) 
                if( (NR>2) && ($i !="NULL"))
                        print $i
}
```

My input looks something like this

```
  NULL   0.435   0.574
 0.533    NULL    NULL
 0.481   0.460    NULL
 0.378   0.568   0.425
  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

And my desired output is something like

```
 0.435   0.574
 0.533   
 0.481   0.460   
 0.378   0.568   0.425
```

Comment: `i+1` in your for loop won't increase `i`. I assume your program is just running forever until you cancel it? Use `++i` instead.

Comment: @jas, you were right. Doing `i=i+1` in the for loop fixed it. Although the output is something not expected

Comment: Great! See my answer for controlling the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the increment part of your `for` statement. `i+1` doesn't change the value of `i`. Use `++i`. Also, you'll want to use `printf` to control when and when not to print newlines. (Note also that here I've used `NR>0` since there weren't any headers in your sample.)

a.awk:

```
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
      if((NR>0) && ($i !="NULL"))
        printf "%.3f ", $i
    }
    print ""
}
```

Test:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file
0.435 0.574 
0.533 
0.481 0.460 
0.378 0.568 0.425
```

Slightly fancier version for controlling better the field separator:

```
{
    sep=""
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
      if((NR>0) && ($i !="NULL")) {
        printf "%s%.3f", sep, $i
        sep=OFS
      }
    }
    print ""
}
```

Comma separator:

```
$ awk -f a.awk OFS=, file
0.435,0.574
0.533
0.481,0.460
0.378,0.568,0.425
```

Tab separator:

```
$ awk -f a.awk OFS='\t' file
0.435   0.574
0.533
0.481   0.460
0.378   0.568   0.425
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `sed` would be the better tool here

```
sed 's/\s*NULL\s*//g' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ sed 's/\s*NULL\s*//g' ./infile
0.435   0.574
0.533
0.481   0.460
0.378   0.568   0.425
```

Comment: nice, but for a input like `0.378    NULL   0.425` this will give `0.3780.425` .. also, `\s` is GNU sed specific afaik, can use `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]` for POSIX compatibility